# while loop. can't hardcode the while statement

Tags: javascript

```
function start() {
    var output = "";
    var index = 0;
    var total = 0;
    var average = 0;
    var arr = []
while(arr.length < 12){
    var randomnumber = Math.ceil(Math.random()*20)
    if(arr.indexOf(randomnumber) > -1) continue;
    arr[arr.length] = randomnumber;
}

    output = output + "List of all values in the array: " + arr;
    output = output + "<br/>" + "Total number of values in the array: " + arr.length + "<br/>";

while(index < arr.length) {
    total = total + arr[index];
    index++;
    }
    average = total / index;
    output = output + "Total of all values: " + total + "<br/>";
    output = output + "Average of all values: " + average;

document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = output;
}
```

I was told I am not allowed to hardcode the statement, how to I go about changing the 'while' statement so I am not hardcoding?

Comment: What do you mean by you can't hardcode the while loop?

Comment: btw, it makes no sense, if you take the dupes out of the array and calculate later an average ...

Comment: @NinaScholz not sure what you mean. It makes sense to take avg of random unique numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably they mean

```
var arr =  new Array(12);
var randIndex=0;

    while(randIndex < arr.length){
        var randomnumber = Math.ceil(Math.random()*20)
        if(arr.indexOf(randomnumber) > -1) continue;
        arr[randIndex] = randomnumber;
        randIndex++;
    }
```

Comment: To avoid any 'hardcoding', OP might also want to consider replacing the `12` with an argument to function `start(length)`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a school assignment. If you are not supposed to hardcode the number of elements in array (currently 12) then you will need to get that number from user in some way. Or alternatively use a random number as shown below.

Note: there is a catch if you let the user specify the number of elements. I'll keep it for you to explore and fix.

```js
function start(len) {
    var output = "";
    var index = 0;
    var total = 0;
    var average = 0;
    var arr = []
while(arr.length < len){
    var randomnumber = Math.ceil(Math.random()*20)
    if(arr.indexOf(randomnumber) > -1) continue;
    arr[arr.length] = randomnumber;
}

    output = output + "List of all values in the array: " + arr;
    output = output + "<br/>" + "Total number of values in the array: " + arr.length + "<br/>";

while(index < arr.length) {
    total = total + arr[index];
    index++;
    }
    average = total / index;
    output = output + "Total of all values: " + total + "<br/>";
    output = output + "Average of all values: " + average;

document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = output;
}

// start(10); // you can get the number of elements in array from user and pass it here. I'm passing hardcoded 10 for now.

start(Math.ceil(Math.random()*20)); // alternatively passing a random number
```

```html
<div id='msg'>
</div>
```